# Javascript execute function after Promise.all

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a set of functions in a promise and after all of them have been executed I need to call a specific function that used the results obtained from each function. This is the code:

```
async function returnValues() {
  var finalVal1;

  function returnValue1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      finalVal1 = {};
      //do stuff
      return finalVal1;
    })
  }
  var finalVal2;

  function returnValue2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      finalVal2 = {};
      //do stuff
      return finalVal2;
    })
  }
  var finalVal3;

  function returnValue3() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      finalVal3 = {};
      //do stuff
      return finalVal3;
    })
  }
  var finalVal4;

  function returnValue4() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      finalVal4 = {};
      //do stuff
      return finalVal4;
    })
  }

  let promise = await Promise.all([returnValue1(), returnValue2(), returnValue3(), returnValue4()]).then(myFunction(finalVal1, finalVal2, finalVal3, finalVal4));
}

function myFunction(finalVal1, finalVal2, finalVal3, finalVal4) {
  console.log(finalVal1);
  console.log(finalVal2);
  console.log(finalVal3);
  console.log(finalVal4);
}
```

The problem is that every returnVal() function is working perfectly fine, and the myFunction() work fine if I'm calling them separately, but when I'm using the Promise.all it never executes the myFunction() bit.
Where am I wrong?
Thank you very much

Comment: "awat" is a typo for a start.

Comment: Your promises never `resolve`. `then(myFunction(...))` calls `myFunction` ***immediately***, not when the promises resolve…

Comment: [Using Promises - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

- Simplified "function that returns a Promise" to a constant.
- Promises do `resolve()`
- The result of `await Promise.all` is an array of values, this array is passed to `myFunction`

```
    async function returnValues() {
    
      const returnValue1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let finalVal1 = {};
          //do stuff
          resolve(finalVal1);
        });
    
     const returnValue2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let finalVal2 = {};
          //do stuff
          resolve(finalVal2);
        })
      }
    
      const values = await Promise.all([returnValue1, returnValue2])
      
      myFunction(values);
    }
    
    function myFunction(values) {
      console.log(values[0]);
      console.log(values[1]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to modify the code like you suggested, but when I'm executing it I get this error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object` when calling the myFunction(). Do you know why?

Comment: No because I have no idea what your code looks like :/

Comment: It was a simple typo. Now I can see the values at the end without errors but myFunction is not called. If i instantly call it manually afterwards it works flawlessly. Do you know why?

Comment: No because I have no idea what your code looks like :/

Comment: Ok no prob, I think this is a logic problem now. Thanks!

Comment: Ha, no worries :) I'm glad this solution worked!